# Rigorous definition for two circuits being equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis, math, equivalent-circuit

Circuits may be rigorously defined in terms of graphs and differentiable functions, as done [here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/network-theory-part-27/).

Yet I have not being able to find a rigorous definition for two circuits (containing only voltage sources, resistors, capacitors, and inductors) being equivalent.

Does anyone know of such a definition?

---

It seems possible to write the definition by means of rules, such as:

1. Given the edges \$e_1, e_2\$  with \$n=t(e_1) = s(e_2)\$, if the node \$n\$ belongs to no other edges, then the circuit is equivalent to that in which \$e_1\$ and \$e_2\$ are replaced by a single edge \$e\$ with \$s(e) = s(e_1)\$ and \$t(e)=t(e_2)\$.

Comment: Tip: for MathJAX on EE.SE use the `\$` opening and closing delimiter.

Comment: Edited to add the \$ delimiters.

Comment: A network N1 is equivalent to a given network N, if they have the same physical behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that two circuits are equivalent if their transfer functions are identical.  In other words, if you put two circuits in respective black boxes with the same set of ports, and you cannot tell the difference between them for any set of conditions, then they are equivalent.

I feel this is a pretty solid definition; proving this equivalence is a different matter.